# How to enable click event in custom component?

Tags: javascript, html, events, custom-controls, webix

Trying to create a custom Webix view, but I cannot enable the `click` event:

Here's my attempt: http://webix.com/snippet/dbab5734

```
webix.protoUI({
  name:"testView",  
  $init:function(config)
  {
    this.$view.innerHTML = '<span class="webix_icon fa-question-circle" style="font-size:50px; margin:10px;"></span>';      
  }, 
  defaults:
  {
    value: "",
    height:60,
    width:60
  },
  on_click:{
    webix_view:function(){
      alert();
    }    
  },  
  setValue:function(value){
    console.log(value);
  },
  getValue:function(){
    return this.config.value
  }   
}, webix.ui.view, webix.EventSystem );
```

Seems like `webix.EventSystem` is not enough, but I can't figure out where's my mistake, as the `on_click` handler works just as needed in other cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the "on_click" which is a mouse event. Hence, you need to add "webix.MouseEvents" alongwith the "webix.ui.view, webix.EventSystem" in your code, and it will work.
Please see:

```
webix.protoUI({
  name:"testView",
/*....your code....*/
  on_click:{
    webix_view:function(){
      webix.message("Hi");

    }    
  },  
/*....your code....*/  
}, webix.MouseEvents, webix.ui.view, webix.EventSystem );
```